# Using VTD-XML to modify element text only

Tags: java, xml, xsd, vtd-xml

I want to achieve below thing in vtd-xml xml modifier class.

```
Original xml 
<xml>
   <element attr1='1' attr2='2' attr3='3'>text</element>
</xml>

int p = vn.getText()
xm.updateToken(p, "new text");
```

But the code here is modifying the text to new text but it's not copying all the attributes. Any idea how to achieve this?

Other option is to call xm.remove() and then add  tag. But, I don't know how to copy the attributes to new tag.

Thank you
Bala

`Edit`

```
testAP.selectXPath("pn[@category]");

while((j = testAP.evalXPath()) != -1)
{
     int p = vn.getText();
     xm.updateToken(p, "new text");
}
```

`XML`

```
<pn category = "ONE" GENERAL0 = "0" GENERAL1 = "-1" >previoustext</pn>
```

Above is the code.

Comment: are you sure it is not copying all the attributes? it is not supposed to behave this way? can you show me the code? which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem... below I used the xml text in your example, the output I got is :

```
                 <pn category="ONE" GENERAL0="0" GENERAL1="-1" >new text</pn>
```

Below is the test code I used

```
        String s = "<pn category=\"ONE\" GENERAL0=\"0\" GENERAL1=\"-1\" >previoustext</pn>";
        vg.setDoc(s.getBytes());
        vg.parse(true);
        vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot testAP = new AutoPilot(vn);
        testAP.selectXPath("/pn[@category]"); 
        xm.bind(vn);
        int j; 
        while((j = testAP.evalXPath()) != -1) 
        { 
             int p = vn.getText(); 
             xm.updateToken(p, "new text"); 
        } 
        XMLByteOutputStream xbos =new XMLByteOutputStream(xm.getUpdatedDocumentSize());
        xm.output(xbos);
        System.out.println(new String(xbos.getXML()));
```

Did you use the latest version of vtd-xml?

Comment: I checked the version in src/java_cup/version.java and it seems to be v10.0k.

public static final int major = 0;

  /*. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .*/

  /** The minor version number. */
  public static final int minor = 10;

  /*. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .*/

  /** The update letter. */
  public static final char update = 'k';

I hope this is not the latest one. can you please confirm.